# change date formatting using java script from imported csv file

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, date-formatting

I have imported CSV file to google-sheet. I have date there which comes up as **11th of August 2019** however I want it to come up as **11/08/2019**. The content of csv file is converted into array and displayed. I am not certain about the approach I can take. I don't want to edit the file. Is there way of doing it without having to edit the file.

I have tried getting the range from the sheet and formatting that way but it doesn't work.

```
  cells.setNumberFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/) library you could just do it as

```
moment(cells, "Do of MMMM YYYY").format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: vanilla js version: 

`const monthMap = { Januar: "01", Februar: "02", August: "08", Dezember: "12"};  

parseInt(cells) + "/" + (monthMap[cells.split(" ")[2]] + "") + "/" + cells.split(" ")[3]`